Does the destination plant in Transport via Plants need to be Large?
The description of Transport via Plants states:

This spell creates a magical link between a Large or larger inanimate plant within range and another plant, at any distance, on the same plane of existence.

At first glance, it seems like the same size restrictions would apply to both plants. You enter a tree and exit from another tree.
However, I'd expect some modifier in the wording of the spell, such as "another similar plant" or even "two Large or larger plants, one in range and one at any distance on the same plane" if that was the case.
You could argue that the destination plant needs to be large enough to come out of, but while it does seem a bit silly, I don't see why the spell couldn't magically shunt you out of, say, a daisy.

The size requirement seems to be only on the first plant.
As you noted, the "destination" plant seems to do not have any size restriction, hence creatures can pop out from a daisy after step into an oak: there are no problems at all, because... Magic!
For comparison, have a look at the Tree Stride spell:

You gain the ability to enter a tree and move from inside it to inside another tree of the same kind within 500 feet. Both trees must be living and at least the same size as you.

It is clear that both trees must have the same size.
But you left out another requirement on the "destination" plant:

You must have seen or touched the destination plant at least once before.

Hence, even if there are no size requirements on the second plant's size, the caster must have seen or touched it at least once in lifetime, which is a more strict requirement than the plant to be Large (or bigger).

As usual, a DM can overrule this and decide that even the destination plant must be of a proper size for letting creatures passing by. Anyway, this makes the usage of this spell a little bit more difficult, since there is a further requirement beside having seen or touched the destination.

Tree Stride is a great comparison! I looked for a similar spell to cross-reference wording but forgot about that one. Also I did omit the familiarity requirement as it was irrelevant to my question, but I'm certainly not forgetting about it :)

By the same reasoning, the destination plant does not have to be inanimate, either.  Which means a druid can send their awakened shrub, with which they are familiar, moving independently toward a target location and then transport once it arrives.
